# SVG rotation around center is moving object

Tags: svg, rotation

I have the following .svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<svg baseProfile="full" height="100cm" version="1.1" width="200cm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect fill="rgb(61, 136, 199)" height="1.0cm" opacity="1.0" transform="rotate(45.0,181.45,181.45)" width="3.0cm" x="0.3144999999999999cm" y="1.3145cm" />
    <circle cx="1.8145cm" cy="1.8145cm" fill="rgb(255, 0, 0)" opacity="1.0" r="0.025cm" />
</svg>
```

which displays like follows:
[image: how the svg looks]

However, I want the rectangle to rotate around the red circle like this:

[image: how I want it to look]

The [Mozilla svg docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#Rotate) state:

`The rotate(<a> [<x> <y>]) transform function specifies a rotation by a degrees about a given point. [...] If optional parameters x and y are supplied, the rotate is about the point (x, y).`

Given that the circle's coordinates are `cx="1.8145cm" cy="1.8145cm"` and the rotation point of the rectangle is `181.45,181.45`, why doesn't the rectangle rotate around the circle?

Note: Changing the rotation point to `1.8145, 1.8145` doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because rotating around `1.8145, 1.8145` (or in other words `1.8145px, 1.8145px`) is not the same as rotating about `1.8145cm, 1.8145cm`.  `px` and `cm` are different units.

The `transform` attribute does not allow coordinates with units, so you will need to convert your centimetre values to pixels.

There are 2.54 cm per inch and 96 px per inch.  So to convert between them, you will need to multiply your cm values by (96/2.54)

```
1.8145 * 96 / 2.54 ~= 68.58
```

So the SVG should be:

```html
<svg baseProfile="full" height="100cm" version="1.1" width="200cm" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect fill="rgb(61, 136, 199)" height="1.0cm" opacity="1.0" transform="rotate(45.0,68.58,68.58)" width="3.0cm" x="0.3144999999999999cm" y="1.3145cm" />
    <circle cx="1.8145cm" cy="1.8145cm" fill="rgb(255, 0, 0)" opacity="1.0" r="0.025cm" />
</svg>
```

Comment: That worked. However, when I tried it with a different rectangle and a different rotation, the rectangle was offset again: https://i.imgur.com/dkswpVF.png https://pastebin.com/raw/izJFmQuW

Comment: Your rotate centres seem to be wrongly calculated.  For instance, `10.0775 * 96 / 2.54 = 380.882`.  That value doesn't match the `x` value in the corresponding transform.

Comment: Whoops, used 2.56 instead of 2.54. Thank you!